# uploaded images in build folder getting deleted after "clean and build" in jsp servlet application in netbeans

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am creating a web application in netbeans 8.0.1 using jsp servlet. In this application, I am uploading images to: "D:\MyPC\NetbeansProjects\MyApplication\build\web\MyImages" by using "request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");",
    But When I am clean and Build the project the image as well as the folder MyImages get deleted.
 So please tell me how to upload and display images from web application root folder.

Answer (score 1):

After building the application - I guess it's an exploded archive - copy the files from the build directory to another folder which should be the deploy folder of your application server.

Comment: I found the solution in little different way- I use "request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");" method and use indexOf() method to find out word "build" and then use substring(0, strg.indexOf("build"));
so I got path of my root directory, further I append the my desire directory (i.e inside "web\MyImages\") to upload my image file.
So when after Clean and Build build folder will contain the copy of all folder and images.

Thank you your consideration.